# null coalescing operator (`??`) giving syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Angular plugin upgrade giving me syntax errors?

Trying to upgrade a plugin on a system built by someone else, I'm a Angular newbie myself, and I'm just replacing the include file with the newer src version, and **it's giving an Unexpected character error on these double question mark operators**:

```
].reduce((res, prop) => res ?? (prop in document.documentElement ? prop : null), null);
```

They look like null coalescing operators, but I thought they were || in Javascript? No one is mentioning this problem in the issues of the plugin github, and it has been this way in all versions for over a year, so I assume this is something I am doing wrong.

This is the plugin: https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `??` operator in JavaScript. What is it you're wanting to achieve? Maybe a little more code would help provide some more context.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to upgrade a plugin with a copy paste of the source code from the creators github, which as far as I can see everyone else seems to think is working fine, so I was thinking this might be some configuration or implementation of Angular I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Nullish Coalescing Operator(`??`) is still experimental in JavaScript. Apparently you can still use it if you include this [Babel Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator). You could try to give that plugin a try or if you already have it see if it is compatible with whatever upgrades you've been making.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that syntax error, you can try this code that has the exact same functionality but without using ES6 or arrow functions, or double question mark.

```
].reduce(function1(res,prop));

function1(res, prop){
    if(res){
        if(prop in document.documentElement){
            return prop;
        }else {return null;}
    }else{return null;}
}
```

Comment: As always, code without explanation is rarely as helpful as code with explanation. For instance, it seems as though all you've done is split the conditional operators into `if/else` blocks... how does that help?

Comment: well, my code helps because OP has a syntax error, so I proposed the exact same functionality in an entire new syntax, without using ES6 or arrow functions, or double question mark.